# How can I round values in geom_text that are contained within other text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, rounding, geom-text

I have some code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

eu_chats %>%
  spread(type, count, fill = 0) %>%   # Spread the count column in missed and completed
  mutate(Total = Completed + Missed) %>%   # Create the Total column
  ggplot(aes(date, Total)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = "Total"),
           colour = "black") + # total bar (with stat = "identity")
  geom_col(aes(y = Missed, fill = "Missed"),
           colour = "black") + # missed bar
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Total chats:", Total)), # add total label
            hjust = -0.05, vjust = 1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("Missed chats:", Missed, "(", Missed/Total*100, "%)")), # add missed label and calculate percentage
            hjust = -0.05, vjust = -0.5, color = "red") + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",  # Manual fill scale
                    values = c("Total" = "forestgreen", "Missed" = "red")) +
  facet_grid(retailer~.) +  # Displayed per retailer
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(eu_chats$count) * 2))
```

Which produces this chart:

[image]

How can I round the values in the `Missed chats:` label to two decimal places?

Other solutions seem only to focus on those cases where no other text is present other than the value itself.

Can this be achieved in my case, whilst still preserving the label text?

Comment: Why can't you simply wrap: `Missed/Total*100` with `round(Missed/Total*100, 2)`?

Comment: I admit, I made an error - when attempting this, I used `round()` but inadvertently applied it incorrectly without realising. Thank you.